How do you define a triangle from its orthographic projections on the 3 axis
I've spent hours on this problem and i'm running out of idea. Say you have an angle in a 3D space made of the points BAC, where A = (0,0,0), B and C can be moved and lengths AB and AC are always equal to 1.
Imagine you cast lights from the negative x,y and z axis. From the angles of the shadows, how do you calculate angle BAC ?
Example 1
Example 2
I've found an answer for a simplified version the segment AB (or AC) is aligned on an axis, but the formula only works because in this case we know the length of on of plane triangle, which is 1.
Since I spent a long time trying to figure it out, I would rather have a hint than the answer so I can try and find it by myself.

Yes, in the simplified problem where a length of 1 is known, that's what I'm doing, but if not the only know informations are the 3 angles, so doing an orthographic projection is the problem here

could I see that simulation ?
